# GDB in Emacs for Program with Command Line Arguments

Tags: emacs, gdb

Does anybody know how so start gdb in emacs when the program requires command line arguments?

I am using this command to create my program

```
/home/cdim/Local/gcc-4.9.2/bin/gfortran -ffree-form -g ./utests/test_gdb.f -o test_gdb
```

Answer (score 3):

Either start `gdb` (When `M-x gdb` prompts you for the debugger) with `--args` or just use the `set args` [command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Arguments.html#Arguments) of `gdb` in the `*gud*` emacs window (the GDB command window under Emacs).

Comment: I am going to `Tools` then `Debugger (GDB)`. Let's start without arguments. Without arguments my program displays help information. I click on the `run` button and nothing happens. I get `Undefined command: "-exec-run".  Try "help".`

Comment: You have a GDB command window under Emacs. Find it, and type commands there.

Comment: I have a window `gud-test_meidum.x`

Comment: I type run `gdb test_meidum.x`, then get the window, I type `run` and I get `Undefined command: "-exec-run". Try "help".`

Comment: I was not using `-i=mi`. Putting it before the executable gets me to gdb and I can run the program using `run` in the window.

Comment: Now the problem that I am facing is setting a setting a breakpoint and having emacs get to that line.